# My program can't write on windows drive

Tags: c++, qt

I have windows 8.1 x64 and I can't write file on my windows drive.  Nothing happens when I run the following code:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionBackup_Database_triggered()
{
    QFile en1;
    en1.copy("En1.txt","C:\\En1.txt");
}
```

Now if I change this code to this:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionBackup_Database_triggered()
{
    QFile en1;
    en1.copy("En1.txt","E:\\En1.txt");  // change C to E
}
```

The code will work correctly.  Why is this?  Note my C drive is my OS drive.

Comment: Afaik writing to C:, C:\Program Files etc. requires special permissions, e.g. running as admin.

Comment: oww i have completely forgot admin permissions thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The copy function returns a `boolean` value which indicates if the copy was successful.

You should use that to see if it copied successfully and handle the case where it doesn't.

The reason it doesn't copy is likely to be file permissions on your c:\ drive. You can change this however you would be better choosing another directory if possible.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfile.html#copy

> bool QFile::copy(const QString & newName)
>
> Copies the file currently specified by fileName() to a file called newName. Returns true if successful; otherwise returns false.
>
> Note that if a file with the name newName already exists, copy() returns false (i.e. QFile will not overwrite it).
>
> The source file is closed before it is copied.

Comment: the reason that i want to access C: drive that is create some folder and files in desktop(public desktop) is there any way to do it without admin permissions?

Comment: @Raminlich: No, by design. Normal users have their own desktops; anything shared is intentionally admin-only  That's what it means to be an admin.

Answer (score 4):

The root of C:\ is protected by the operating system, as there are important (and hidden) files there.

The program needs to run as admin, or write somewhere else.  ProgramData is a more appropriate place - these have CSIDs which can be found using shell folder operations. (Or environment variables).